# i try to install library for vue project and return error

Tags: npm, vue.js, npm-install

I tried to install & execute old vue project.

The problem is when I execute `npm install` there are many errors.

I dont know why, because some time ago the projects worked without errors:

error file : https://gist.github.com/scaltro/5f6b04c3c1fa192989ddbb1c8707e233

Comment: Do you have the updated and stable version of node and npm?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no npm guru, but [this line](https://gist.github.com/scaltro/5f6b04c3c1fa192989ddbb1c8707e233#file-error-log-L3009) seems to tell you what to do?

```
warn file-loader@1.1.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: how i can install this ?

Comment: npm install webpack is what I'd try.

Answer (score 0):

Try with: 
`npm install file-loader@1.1.5`